# R function for recognizing name variants?

Tags: r, string

I'm working with a big dataset of names and need to be able to group by the individual. It's possible that in the dataset there are names that appear different but are the same person, such as John Doe or John A. Doe, or Michael Smith and Mike Smith. Is there a way for R to find instances like these and recognize them as the same person?

```
df <- data.frame(
  name = c("John Doe", "John A. Doe", "Jane Smith", "Jane Anderson", "Jane Anderson Lowell",
           "Jane B. Smith", "John Doe", "Jane Smith", "Michael Smith",
"Mike Smith", "A.K. Ross", "Ana Kristina Ross"),
  rating = c(1,2,1,1,2,3,1,4,2,1,3,2)
)
```

Here, there are multiple repeated individuals, whether the variant be a middle initial, a shortened name, a lengthened name, or someone whose last name changed. I've been trying to find a function that could give a similarity percentage of characters in name matches, and from there I could manually examine cases of high percentage to evaluate if they are indeed the same person. My end goal is to find the average rating by person, where I would need to sort by the individual.

Comment: If `John A. Doe` = `John Doe` and `John B. Doe` = `John Doe`, does `John A. Doe` = `John B. Doe`?

Answer (score 0):

The actual solution depends on your data and the variations that it can have. How can you identify one unique individual? Maybe extracting first and last name from each `name` would help?

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  group_by(firstname = word(name, 1), 
           lastname = word(name, -1)) %>%
  summarise(rating = mean(rating)) %>%
  ungroup

# firstname lastname rating
#  <chr>     <chr>     <dbl>
#1 Jane      Anderson   1   
#2 Jane      Smith      1.33
#3 John      Doe        2
```

Answer (score 0):

We could do this with `extract` from `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
    tidyr::extract(name, into = c('firstname', 'lastname'), 
        "^(\\w+).*\\s(\\w+)$") %>% 
    group_by(firstname, lastname) %>% 
    summarise(rating = mean(rating, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  firstname lastname rating
  <chr>     <chr>     <dbl>
1 Jane      Anderson   1   
2 Jane      Smith      1.33
3 John      Doe        2
```